# И снова адаптивная верстка

Tags: css

Есть блок #main фиксированный ширины 1000 px.

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

В него вложены 4 блока по 230px, у каждого блока по краям отступы 10px (типа модульная сетка)

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
    <div class="grid_4"></div>
</div>
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы на экранах максиамальной ширины 480px блоки grid_4 растягивались по всей ширине экрана и были друг под другом? Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #main {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .grid_4 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю, что вам не хочется разбираться в адаптивной верстке и media queries, вам просто нужно чтобы это работало ?! Тогда почему бы вам не использовать готовые решения, а именно готовые адаптивные сетки ?!  Обязательно [ознакомьтесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/156747/).

Comment: А для #main какую ширину выставлять?

Comment: Дописал в примере, 100%